# Is work done on paid time off “work for hire” in California?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, employment

I am curious about this, because my understanding was that unless my employment contract stated to the contrary, work done in my spare time without using company resources is not “work for hire” in California.

I am unsure if work done on paid time off counts as “spare time,” though. It seems like because it is time off, it should, but I am being compensated.

So if I am on PTO for vacation and happen to work on a side project, does my employer own the copyright?